# Stream Multiple PDFs to render in Browser

Tags: spring-mvc, pdf, servlets, pdf.js, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm in need of a way to stream multiple PDFs to be rendered in browser as one. The challenges are multiple.

1. The files are too large and I don't have a static copy on the server. I retrieve it from back-end and stream. The retrieval is not as a stream but a byte array. I cannot change the behavior of the back-end.
2. I have the option of retrieving the PDF in one go, which takes too much time as some PDFs run in thousands. Other option is to retrieve in segments, which gives multiple individual PDFs.
3. The number of pages or length cannot be determined as the API is not too reliable.

My question is - Is there a way to combine and stream byte arrays of multiple PDF into one stream and render it in browser?

I've tried to just stream byte array of one PDF after another. However, the browser renders the first PDF only and that too only after I close the stream.

I'm OK to use any JavaScript solution like PDF.js, provider I'm able to show and let the users print/save the whole document.

It is a Spring MVC application with JSF as front-end on Websphere application Server. I have the liberty of adding open source libraries as dependencies if required.

Comment: It's not really clear by p.3 especially "length cannot be determined". In most of the cases, tail of the PDF files must be read to display the document. The PDF.js is capable of fetching portion of the PDF using HTTP range requests to fetch data to display only first visible pages. See its demo with network monitor opened in Firefox or Chrome. If you cannot setup HTTP range requests, you shall create your own api for https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/58329f7f92f9c9f5dd8a7e42caf6ba3afdd6911d/src/display/api.js#L557

Comment: @async5, the problem is that the documents are stored in AFP format and I convert those to PDF. So, the length of the array could not be determined before conversion of the whole document.

Comment: Then you will never have complete PDF document until conversion stops to generate tail section/xref of the pages (even linearized PDF documents need to know full length of the file). You can start streaming when conversion ends.

Comment: @async5, Is it possible to append a complete document to another complete document in response without closing? What I am asking is this - stream one complete document to outputstream, follow it by another complete PDF.

Comment: It will not be a valid PDF document when you just concatenate binary data -- you will need to add combined xref of all documents at end, so any PDF viewer will be able to parse them. Many tools can combine multiple document into one (e.g. pdftk, but not PDF.js) but this requires complete conversion of all smaller documents to re-parse and combine them.